# How do I add custom domains that are required to implement email link authentication in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting

I want to add a custom domain that is required to modify the email template of firebase authentication. However, if I want to verify the domain from Firebase with the domain address I purchased, I should add the following DNS records in my domain registrar. So I add DNS records whose types were TXT and CNAME as instructed, but I failed to verify domain.
I want to know if the cause of this problem is in the process of adding DNS records, or if it is because another process should have been done first, but it cannot be done. "another process" refers to, for example, whether Firebase hosting should have deployed first.

I added DNS records like below.

[image: 1]

And then I requested a confirmation again in email templates in Firebase authentication, but I failed.

Comment: Without [clear reproduction of what you've done](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it'll be hard for anyone to say what went wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I revised the article again more specifically.